# How to grab a variable and use it as a prop in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, scope, components

I am trying to pass a value to a component in my react app. The value lives inside a function and when I try to render it as a prop in the react component it is undefined. How can I access this variable properly? P.S the variable is tableSiteId; Also what is the best practice for building these components in general?

```js
async getSiteInfo(companyId, companyName, divisions, userId, userType){
  var userinv = []
  for(let key in this.state.userInventory){
    userinv.push(this.state.userInventory[key])
  }
  var inv=userinv[2]
  var fullUserInv = []
  var userInvArr=[]
  
await Promise.all(
      inv.map(async key => {
        return fetch(backendUrl +'/getsiteinfo', {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
    
          //make sure to serialize your JSON body
          body: JSON.stringify({
            site_id:key.site_id
        })
        
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        //Uncomment below to view the response as a console log. Note, the data will not be pulled into the table if you do this//
        // .then(response=>console.log(response))
    /* THIS NEEDS TO BE FIXED, SOME USERS CANNOT GET ALL OF THEIR DATA BECAUSE THEIR ORGS DO NOT CONTAIN DIVERSITY OR GEOGRAPHY */
        .then(data1 =>{ 
          var diversities = '';
          var geo = '';
          var location = '';
          var site_id = '';
          if(data1.site_metadata) location = data1.site_metadata.company_state_full;
          if(data1.site_metadata) site_id = data1.site_metadata.site_id;
          if(data1.diversities) diversities = data1.diversities[0].diversity;
          // if(data1.locations) geo = data1.locations[0].geography;
          userInvArr.push([data1.site_metadata.site_name, "N/A", diversities, location,
          `<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notes-modal" data-site_id="${site_id}" class="btn btn-primary add-notes-btn">Create</button><button type="button" data-site_id="${site_id}" class="btn btn-primary view-notes-btn">View</button></div>`
        
        ])
        })
        // `<button class="button primary notes-btn" data-site_id="${site_id}">Notes</button>`
    .then(()=>{
        this.setState({
            inventoryNewData:userInvArr,
            fullUserInventory:fullUserInv,
            viewUserInventory:true
        })
          })
          .then(()=>{
  //function for generating the user table before datatables plugin styles it//

        CreateUserTable(userInvArr)

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

                //---------------DATATABLES PLUGIN-------------------//

        var row_count = $('#user-table-body tr').length;
        this.setState({
          counter:row_count
        })
        let table = $('#user-table-body').DataTable(
          {
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>",
            "pageLength": 15,
          lengthMenu: [ 1, 5, 10, 15, 20],
          language: {searchPlaceholder: "Search Organizations and Contacts" , search: "", paginate: {
            'next': '<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>',
            'previous': '<i class="icon-angle-left"></i>'
    },sLengthMenu: " _MENU_" }
     
    
        });  
        $('#ofccp-search-keyword1').keyup(function(){
          table.search($(this).val()).draw()
    })
        $('#ofccp-search-keyword2').on('change',function(){
          table.columns(2).search($(this).val()).draw(); //Exact value, column, reg
        });
    
        $('#ofccp-search-keyword3').keyup(function(){
          table.columns(3).search($(this).val()).draw();
    })
  })
}))

//-----------------------------------------------CREATE BUTTON TO NAVIGATE TO ADD ORG PAGE---------------------------------------------------------//
this.createButton()

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

                  //-------------------------NOTES LOGIC FOR CREATING AND VIEWING-----------------------------------//


         

//declare tableSiteId variable//
  var tableSiteId;
//----------Initializing tableSiteId variable------------//                  
$('.add-notes-btn').on( 'click', function noteTitle (e) {
     tableSiteId= $(this).data("site_id")
       
    })

     //------First onclick is for creating the note and storing in mongoDB---//
    $('.submit-note').on( 'click', function (e) {
      // $('#modalName').val(tableOrgName)
      fetch(backendUrl +'/notes', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },

      //make sure to serialize your JSON body
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user_id:userId,
        content:$("#message-text").val(),
        site_id:parseInt(tableSiteId),
        company_id:parseInt(companyId),
        company_name:companyName,
        divisions:parseInt(divisions),
        user_type:userType
        
    })
    
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data=>console.log(data))
  })

//----------Second onclick is for viewing the notes based on company ID and site ID--------------//

$('.view-notes-btn').on( 'click', function (e) {
    let tableSiteId= $(this).data("site_id")
    fetch(backendUrl +'/getnotes', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        user_id:userId,
        site_id:parseInt(tableSiteId),
        company_id:parseInt(companyId),
        user_type:userType
        
    })
    })  
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data=>console.log(data))
  })
}
```

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="notes-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="notes-modal" aria-hidden="true">    
 <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h5 className="modal-header-description" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add New Note</h5>
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
          <CreateNote tableSiteId={this.tableSiteId}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            <div id='header'></div>
            <section className="outer-container">
                <div className="container container-wrapper">
                  <div className="row">
            
                  <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="header-group">
                        <h2 id="page-title" className="page-title"><img src={Logo} className='logo' />OFCCP Local Outreach</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `tableSiteId` isn't part of any react state, and therefore it isn't part of any react component lifecycle updates, i.e. react doesn't rerender anything when `tableSiteId` updates. Mixing jquery and react is generally an anti-pattern as they have ***very*** orthogonal approaches to UI. Jquery operates directly on the DOM and react within its VirtualDOM. Try to fully convert the component code over to react by utilizing component state and lifecycle. Other than a couple `this.setState` statements where is your react code?

Comment: Hey Drew, Well I do have some more code on that same page I just displayed that one function. Yeah, not the best with react but I am actively learning. I tried to setState inside that jquery onclick but it says that this.setState is not a function. Can you walk me through how to do this in more detail? Newbie alert sorry.

Comment: No worries, we all started from 0 at some point. Unfortunately though, IMO, in order to get this code "react-y-fied" would require a significant rewrite which is a bit outside the scope of SO. There are many tutorials and documentations out there for writing, creating, and converting code to react components. What ***is*** more in scope is attempting the rewrite and updating your question with what isn't working in react. I suggest simply starting with the [react for beginners](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#react-for-beginners) or if that is too slow jump to the Main concepts.